# User account creation issue and no logout - Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

There was a erfectly functional 1.6.1.7 prestasite before trying to upgrade, we since tried to restore but not all files copied over as per Softaculous.

The issue is users are unable to create an account nor existing users able to log out. Error debug is one and does not show anything. bedandwood.com is the site. I ensure header.tpl has a centre column but most of the code is untouched. Is there something in cookie or token that is causing the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We reinstalled the shop, given there was no response.